# How to append json object to the table through ajax with time delay in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm new to js & jquery, I am create a json object to display the data in table through external json. But i want to add data in the json file, the data automatically updated in the table.

```
$(window).load(function(){      
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var url='json/data.json';
        $.getJSON(url, function (r) {

            for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
                var tr = $('<tr>');

                tr.append("<td>" + r[i].User_Name + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + r[i].score + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + r[i].team + "</td>");
                $('tbody').append(tr);
            } 

        }); 

    });
});

 <table id="racer_details">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

my json data is,

```
[
    {
        "User_Name":"John Doe",
        "score":"10",
        "team":"1"
    },
    {
        "User_Name":"Jane Smith",
        "score":"15",
        "team":"2"
    },
    {
        "User_Name":"Chuck Berry",
        "score":"12",
        "team":"2"
    }
]
```

This is my sample data, first i add 3 values to the table but i want to update the values to the table with time delay, if i want to add some values in json it will automatically update values in the table after time delay. How is it possible with jquery with ajax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get data from json array into table format using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53589368/how-to-get-data-from-json-array-into-table-format-using-jquery)

Comment: Put your GET in a timer, and keep doing append()

Comment: if i put timer in this function, 3 data will displayed continuously after time delay. I want the given 3 data with newly added data in the table

Comment: Oh, you mean you will append more data to the JSON, and it should update the table?

Comment: yes, I will append data to the table with timer.

Comment: put this function into timer, Add an Array of usernames(outside the function), and check the username in array before appending the table.

Comment: I will try functions with timer, it will not works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
   <table id="racer_details">
    <tbody id="racer_data">
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

JS: You can show data like this using ajax,

```
$(window).load(function(){      
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
           type:"GET",
           url:"xyz",
           data:{ 'xyz': xyz },
           contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType:"json",
           success:function (result){
              var dataTab = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(result));
              $.each(dataTab.data, function (index, value) {
                    $("#racer_data").append('<tr>'+value.name+'</tr>
                                 <tr>'+value.scor+'</tr>
                                 <tr>'+value.team+'</tr>'
              },
             error: function(){},
          });

    });
});
```